# Why won't my image show in my HTML file despite the correct location?

Tags: html, image, filepath, src

This is my FTP files:

```
[folder] resources
    -> [png] header.png
    -> [png] leftpanel.png
    -> [png] button_prd.png
    -> [png] button_hp.png
[jpg] header.jpg
[png] header.png
[html] index.html
[html] aboutus.html
[png] button_prd.png
[html] contactus.html
[html] products.html
[css] style.css
```

I know it's a bit messy, but it's only because I can't figure it out. Why my image won't show up.

I've tried using both the direct path:

```
<img src="header.png">
```

and using the resources file.

```
<img src="resources/header.png">
```

So can anyone help me with why I can't get my image to show?

Comment: where did you put your `index file` ?

Comment: it's in the main directory. Same one with aboutus.html // contactus.html // products/html.

Comment: Does it say 404 on the browser console?

Comment: console gives:Failed to load resource http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's case sensitive. Your file is named Header.png, not header.png

I checked the resources dir to see if I could see the index listing, which I could. Then I saw your Header.png there and took a shot in the dark to see if the one in the root was also called Header.png. Indeed it is.